# Writing file name in java

Tags: java, file

Supposedly the user will enter their "ID #: 1203103" then after that it will automatically create a text file named 1203103.txt  How can I do that? Here is my code. what will I change in my code?

```
String id = scan.nextLine();
File file = new File(id.txt);
FileWriter fileWrite = new FileWriter(file);
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWrite);
```

Comment: I suggest always use try catch i.e exception handling and when exception occurred try to understand it and goggle it with exception message. :)

Comment: @Mubasher Since the OP's code doesn't even compile, exception handling won't help. Also, you will always get the exception message without a try...catch. This is certainly preferable for run time errors.

Answer (score 2):

You should also surround the creation of the file with a try and catch block, and when you're done with the file close it like so:

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String id = scan.nextLine();
    File file = new File(id + ".txt");
    FileWriter fileWrite = null;
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = null;
    try {
        fileWrite = new FileWriter(file);
        bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWrite);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            scan.close();
            fileWrite.close();
            bufferedWriter.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can't use `File file = new File(id.txt);` as it takes string argument.so you can make a `string` like `id+".txt"` and then pass it to `new file();`

```
String id = scan.nextLine();
File file = new File(id+".txt");
FileWriter fileWrite = new FileWriter(file);
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWrite);
```

Comment: Please explain how your change fixes the problem.

Comment: @AngelaVinagrera you too

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a `String` for the file name with the expected format. To do this, you can simply use the `+` operator which concatenates `String`s (and automatically converts non-Strings to Strings):

```
String filename = id + ".txt";
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a different approach by using [try with resource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

```
String id = scan.nextLine();
try(BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(id + ".txt")))
{
}
catch(Exception e)
{
}
```